# Crm dynamics custom action after clicking Invoice Paid

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

In MS CRM When user clicks Invoice Paid, I need to notify external site that this invoice was paid
Is this possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  There are two separate ways I can think of to do this:

1. [Hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309322.aspx) and [recreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334341.aspx) the Invoice Paid button via the CRM's RibbonXML and use your own javascript methods to change the status of the invoice to "Paid" and also talk to the external site.  This would work so long as the only way the Invoice's status is changed to Paid is via the Invoice Paid button.
2. When you click the invoice paid, the value of the `StateCode` property of the Invoice changes to "Paid", which is a value of 2.  So, you can also [register a plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx) that fires on the Update message of the Invoice and check the before and after properties of the entity to see if the `StateCode` was not equal to "Paid" in the [Pre Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959593.aspx) and equal to "Paid" in the [Post Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959592.aspx).  This would be a server-side solution and would work no matter how the Invoice Paid action was triggered, and also gives you access to the .NET framework.

Comment: As this is a business process which should be run every time the status changes to 'paid' you should use either a plugin or a workflow. Client scripting is not the appropriate tool for this requirement

Comment: Thanks, registering a plugin is what I need