# Marking an Invoice as Paid in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514625/crm-dynamics-custom-action-after-clicking-invoice-paid).

I'm trying to mark an existing Invoice as Paid in Dynamics CRM 2011 using Silverlight.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594422.aspx), all I need to do is set the Status Code = 100001 and the State Code = 2.

When I do this I get a "NotFound" exception.

```
Guid invoiceID = new Guid("Existing Invoice Guid");
IOrganizationService orgService = OrgServiceFactory.GetInstance();

orgService.BeginRetrieve("invoice", invoiceID, new ColumnSet(new string[] { "invoiceid", "statecode", "statuscode" }), (result) =>
{
    var fetchResp = orgService.EndRetrieve(result);

    var statecodeAttrib = fetchResp.Attributes.Single(a => a.Key == "statecode");
    OptionSetValue statecode = (OptionSetValue)statecodeAttrib.Value;
    statecode.Value = 2; 


    var statuscodeAttrib = fetchResp.Attributes.Single(a => a.Key == "statuscode");
    OptionSetValue statuscode = (OptionSetValue)statuscodeAttrib.Value;
    statuscode.Value = 100001;

    orgService.BeginUpdate(fetchResp, (updateResult) =>
    {
        /* Web Exception thrown here */
        orgService.EndUpdate(updateResult);
        Console.Write("");
    }, orgService);

}, orgService);
```

If I remove the "statecode" bit, and just try and set the statuscode to 2 - (Partially Shipped) or 4 - (Billed) it works as expected.

It is only when I try and set both it fails.  It also fails if I just try and set statuscode = 100001, 100002, 100003 (Complete, Partial, Canceled)

Is there another way to mark an invoice as paid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change a record's State, you always need to execute a separate SetState request as opposed to just a simple update to the state and statuscode. In your case, you can do a [SetStateDynamicEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959534.aspx) or [SetStateInvoice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959539.aspx) request.

Unfortunately, those messages are not available from the OData service in CRM 2011. What you'll need to do is use the SOAP web service through Silverlight. The [SDK has a walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594452.aspx), and if you want a head start, the [SilverCRMSoap](http://silvercrmsoap.codeplex.com/) library is a good quick implementation of that walkthrough.

Comment: It's odd that I can set the status code to 2 or 3, but not the others.

Comment: You can change the status code to another status in the same state just using an update, but if you change the state you need to actually send the SetState message.

Answer (score 4):

Executing a standard SetState request will also work, negating the need to establish a SOAP connection.

```
SetStateRequest request = new SetStateRequest();
request.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(Invoice.EntityLogicalName, invoice.Id);
request.State = new OptionSetValue ((int)InvoiceState.Paid);
request.Status = new OptionSetValue (100001); // Complete
SetStateResponse response = (SetStateResponse)_service.Execute(request);
```